# Tensorflow 2.0: How to pass a random sequence to decoder input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

my model is like

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(5, 5))
encoder = GRU(128, return_state=True, return_sequences=False)
_, H = encoder(encoder_inputs)
decoder = GRU(128, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_output = decoder(tf.random.uniform((3, 1)), initial_state=H)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(decoder_output)
model = Model([encoder_inputs], decoder_output)
```

I wanted to control the length of decoder_output,so I passed a random seqence made by `(tf.random.uniform((3, 1)`

It gives me this error

```
raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank at least %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (1, 3) must have rank at least 3
```

How can I fix it or any simple alternative way to control the output of seqence to  seqence model?

Comment: return_sequences=False in the first GRU layer doesn't permit the second GRU to receive a sequence.... this a problem, but in general I see some noise in the code

Comment: It is not the second GRU. It's seq2seq model which the decoder(the second) only pass the weight of encoder (the first)

Comment: the decoder must receive an input/layer of 3D shape (a sequence) you can't provide tf.random.uniform... I can provide you the correct structure

Comment: I know, the 3D shape I want to pass is (Batch, 3  , 1)

Comment: tf.random.uniform((3, 1)) (which is not correct) is not (Batch, 3 , 1)